# 16.10 System Disables Network Connections

Tags: ssh, network-manager, suspend, connection

I am using a Ubuntu system remotely via ssh. After some time (approx. 15 min). It disconnects all network connections. When I connect a monitor cable it re-activates everything. I disabled 'screen-lock' and suspend in the power menu.

How can I make the ssh connection permanently available?

Comment: create a `config` file in `.ssh` and add `ServerAliveInterval 15` to send ping to remote machine so it always remains connected. __Note:__ you can change the 15 (which is in seconds) to any value you like.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to prevent this issue:

1. From local system:

   - create a `config` file in `~/.ssh` and add the following

     ```
     ServerAliveInterval 15
     ```
   - this will send `null packets` to remote host.
2. From Server end:

   - open the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and add the follwing:

     ```
     ServerAliveInterval 60
     ```
   - also if you don't have **root access** or just wish to configure for own account, then add to `~/.ssh/config` (create if it doesn't exist):

     ```
     Host *
        ServerAliveInterval 60
     ```
3. Restart remote machine or your local machine as the case may be.

Information:

- Change the time to suit you.
- In the case of setting it from the remote side and for personal use run `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config` to change permissions on the `config` file (recommendation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084288/keep-ssh-session-alive))

Comment: Sounds good. I will try and as soon as I have access to the machine.